# 3D vector with 2 unknown sizes and 1 known size

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

My program receives 2 dimensions as command-line arguments (M as width and N as height). I must handle any dimensions as long as M and N are between [3-10000].

I want to compute values in a matrix (represented by the 3D vector), but I want to keep the previous values to compute the new values (which is why one dimension is only 2-deep : 0=old, 1=new).

This will give me a structure like `matrix[M][N][2]` or `matrix[2][M][N]`. I do not have a preference (whichever is more simple, probably the latter).

Since the M and N are known only at runtime, I cannot use simple arrays (well I could with double ***arr but I don't want to mess with memory allocation)

Should I use a vector for each of the 3 dimensions or only for those that are not known? In other words, should I use a simple array for the 0=old, 1=new and vectors for M and N?

Whichever is chosen, I am struggling to make it work. How do I create and initialize it?

Comment: If your data types are simple arithmetic data types, like int, float, double, complex, etc, you can use any of the numerous matrix and linear algebra libraries. There is boost::numeric::ublas, Eigen, LAPACK, OpenCV, etc. I had good experience with Eigen and would recommend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I use a `vector` for each of the 3 dimensions?

Yes, you should.

There is no advantage to writing your own code for memory allocation and deallocation when the standard library provides you with the functionality.

> Whichever is chosen, I am struggling to make it work, how do I create and initialize it?

Assuming you have figured out how to get `M` and `N` from the command line, you can use:

```
std::vector<int> d1(N, 0);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> d2(M, d1);
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> matrix(2, d2);
```

You can combine that into one line also:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> matrix(2, std::vector<std::vector<int>>(M, std::vector<int>(N, 0)));
```

I prefer the first method. It's easier to follow what's being done.

Comment: With this I can use the matrix as `matrix[i][j][0]` or is it `matrix[0][i][j]` ? `i` being `M` and `j` being `N` ?

With the way it is declared I'm not sure which way it is when I use it with the square brackets

Comment: The second term - `matrix[0][i][j]`.

Comment: Is it possible to do a kind of typedef with this once I get the M and N?

I want to make functions to initialise it and print it to console, it would be nice to be able to use a custom typedef instead of having vectors of vectors everytime, like `void myFunc(myCustomVectorMatrixType mat)`, do you get what I mean?

Comment: You cannot use a `typedef` using `M` and `N` unless `M` and `N` are known at compile time.

Comment: well maybe ot using M N, the functions don't need to know the vector sizes since it's built in the object already right? I could typedef a vector<vector<vector<double>>> or something like that?

Comment: Yes. you certainly can do that. @MikeMB has created some useful type aliases [in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29420246/434551) that you can use as starting points.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using only two matrices I'd use an array of length 2:

```
std::array<std::vector<std::vector<int>>, 2 > matrices{ {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>(M, std::vector<int>(N, 0)),
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>(M, std::vector<int>(N, 0))
} };
```

usage:

```
int a=matrices[0][M][N];
```

Although I think your program would benefit from some type aliases. Here is a complete example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
using Row = std::vector < T > ;

template<class T>
using Matrix = std::vector < Row<T> > ;

std::array<Matrix<int>, 2 > matrices;

int main()
{
    size_t M, N;
    int d;
    std::cin >> M;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::cin >> default;
    matrices.fill(Matrix<int>(M, Row<int>(N,d)));

    for (auto& r : matrices[0]){
        for (auto& e : r) {
            std::cout << e << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```